Calculating P1 P2 and Offset
PLEASE HELP ME IF YOU'RE LEGEND
A system with 2-level page table, the frame size is 4KB; the address register is 32 bits, the
row size of the page table is 4 bytes; the address register is divided into (p1, p2, offset) for
fast address translation (no need to use multiplication and addition for calculating the
physical address). Given a reference =4200746, the corresponding (p1, p2, offset) is?
Select one:
(2, 3, 256)
(1, 2, 256)
(0, 1026, 256)
(1, 3, 256)
I try solve it but i cant and i'm in illustration of knowledge
